# Android Wear app. This app is incompatible with your device

Tags: google-play, wear-os, incompatibility

I just published my app for wear devices, its the Watch Face, don't have any UI for phone app. I uploaded to the Google Play. 
But it says  This app is incompatible with your device. To all users or Devices.

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 3):

Since Android Wear application are only in sync with a handheld device, it needs to have a corresponding application in the handheld device.

Let me make it little more clear:
To install anything on Android Wear, you need to have corresponding application for mobile, which will sync up its corresponding wear part and install the same on wear.

So go ahead develop a dummy kind of an application for handheld.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation, in order to publish a wearable app without a phone app component, you need to raise your minimum target SDK version to 2.0.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps.html